# Why are all the ink! Playground links broken in the official Substrate docs at substrate.dev?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, documentation, playground

If I go to https://substrate.io/developers/smart-contracts/ and click on any of the 6x hyperlinks called [Open ink! Playground](https://ink-playground.substrate.io/) it takes me to https://ink-playground.substrate.io/ and returns `404 page not found`.

But at https://substrate.io/developers/smart-contracts/ if I click the Developer > [Playground](https://substrate.io/developers/playground/) link in the footer it takes me to https://substrate.io/developers/playground/ where I can launch Substrate Node Template at https://playground.substrate.dev/?deploy=node-template or launch Substrate Front-End Template at https://playground.substrate.dev/?deploy=front-end-template.

Why are the all the ink! Playground links broken and does the official Substrate docs website use a broken link validator tool to update a site service health status page anywhere?

Comment: Thank you for noting this. I will let the docs team know asap

Comment: Contributions will be welcomed :) https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1974

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in this [PR](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1974#issuecomment-1533878806) and will fix the issue mentioned