# Is ink! playground closed?

Tags: ink

- I accessed the URL below.
- https://ink-playground.substrate.io/
- However, HTTP Status Code 404 is returned and this site cannot be used.
- Has this site been closed?

Comment: duplicate of https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8280/why-are-all-the-ink-playground-links-broken-in-the-official-substrate-docs-at-s

Comment: I apologize for my insufficient confirmation and for asking a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

We are working with ChainIDE to get an ink! IDE working. You can already test it out here: https://develop-2egludalf0.chainide.com/s/dashboard/projects